# Need to get the total count for distinct Id's in scala for same file

Tags: scala

```
val someData = Seq(
  Row("test.zip", "abc1","A"),
  Row("test.zip", "abc1","B"),
  Row("test.zip", "abc3","C")  
  )

val someSchema = List(
  StructField("file_name", StringType, true),
  StructField("id", StringType, true),
  StructField("chart_char", StringType, true) 
)

val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)
```

Need the below result, that is total count of the distinct ids for that respective file_name

Expected Result:

`file_name,count
test.zip   2`

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = Seq(
  ("test.zip", "abc1","A"),
  ("test.zip", "abc1","B"),
  ("test.zip", "abc3","C"),
  ("test2.zip", "abc1","C")

).toDF("file_name","id","chart_char")

df.show()

//+---------+----+----------+
//|file_name|  id|chart_char|
//+---------+----+----------+
//| test.zip|abc1|         A|
//| test.zip|abc1|         B|
//| test.zip|abc3|         C|
//|test2.zip|abc1|         C|
//+---------+----+----------+

df.select("file_name", "id")
  .distinct()
  .groupBy("file_name")
  .count
  .show

//+---------+-----+
//|file_name|count|
//+---------+-----+
//| test.zip|    2|
//|test2.zip|    1|
//+---------+-----+
```